# Why can't my botpress NLU find the number in 1100cm?

Tags: nlu, botpress

I use Botpress V12 selfhosted.

I have a NLU intent in botpress that should get the sizes of trucks out of the answer.
The intent includes short and long answers to train the bot.
One problem keeps occuring: the bot understands '1100 cm' but not '1100cm'.

My intent looks like this:

[image: My intent looks like this:]

I expected the bot to get the 1100 out of '1100cm' but it couldn't do it.